# Library Projects with @Background annotation giving Multiple dex files error

Tags: android, android-annotations

I have two projects Project A is a library project, Project B is the main project and has an dependency on Project A.

I'm getting following error when I use @ Background annotation in both projects.

```
  Unable to execute dex: Multiple dex files define Lorg/androidannotations/api/BackgroundExecutor$Task;
```

I think the reason is both projects generate `org.androidannotations.api.BackgroundExecutor`class.

Any solution??

(I'm using Android Annotations V 3.0 Snapshot)

Comment: It may be because of multiple jar files are added in your application. please check in your Project>BuildPath

Comment: Ye I got your point, but this is not related to jar files, I kept all my external jar files inside most super library project. here the issue is both project A and project B generates BackgroundExecutor class inside .apt_generated folder.

Comment: Can you post your logcat error and relevant structure of your application?

Comment: There is no logcat error or stacktrace, this is compile time error. I think this is related to class generation strategy in androidannotations

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue is addressed in the new android annotation release [3.0.1](https://github.com/excilys/androidannotations/wiki/ReleaseNotes#wiki-3.0.1)
Now we can use @Background annotation in library projects without any issue.